# how to style my for dices to be in a row, rather than below each other

Tags: css, styles

No matter what styling i do, my four dice won't all go in one row. The dice go in pairs, and one pair is below the other whereas i want them to be in a row. I don't know if i am naming them wrong or i don't know, sorry i am new to javascript

here is my code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bigdice.css">


<body>
          <div id  = "dice1"> Player 1


<script type ='text/javascript'> 
    var player1Dice1 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var player1Dice2 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;</script> </div>


 <div id  = "dice2"> Player 2   
   <script> 


   var player2Dice1 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;
    var player2Dice2 = Math.floor (Math.random()*6)+1;

    var scoreP1 = player1Dice1 + player1Dice2;
    var scoreP2 = player2Dice1 + player2Dice2;

    var opentag = " <img src = 'die";
    var closetag = ".gif'>"; </script> </div>

    <div><script>
    var p1d1 = opentag + player1Dice1 + closetag; 
    var p1d2 = opentag + player1Dice2 + closetag; </script> </div>

   <div>
   <script> var p2d1 = opentag + player2Dice1 + closetag;
    var p2d2 = opentag + player2Dice2 + closetag; </script> </div>
    <script>




    document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP1);
    document.write(p1d1);
    document.write(p1d2);
    document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP2);
    document.write(p2d1);
    document.write(p2d2);
    if (scoreP1 > scoreP2) {
        document.write("<div>Player 1 wins.</div>");
    }
    else if (scoreP2 > scoreP1) {
        document.write("<div>Player 2 wins.</div>");
    }
    else {
        document.write("<div>Draw.</div>"); 
    }





    if (scoreP1 < scoreP2) {
        document.write("<div>Player 1 loses.</div>");
    }
    else if (scoreP2 < scoreP1) {
        document.write("<div>Player 2 loses.</div>");
    }
    else {
        document.write("<div>Draw.</div>"); 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS as well.

Comment: all i have so far is #dice1
{ left:100px
}

#dice
right: 100px
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all four dice to be in the same row you should change this:

```
document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP1);
document.write(p1d1);
document.write(p1d2);
document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP2);
document.write(p2d1);
document.write(p2d2);
```

To:

```
document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP1 + "</div>");
document.write ("<div>Score: " + scoreP2 + "</div>");
document.write(p1d1 + p1d2 + p2d1 + p2d2);
```

If you later decide to place them in a `div` you can use `document.getElementById();`

Comment: that works, but i want the player 1 to go above the first pair and player 2 above the second pair ? and same with the winner and loser ? how do i do that

Comment: @denis hassle Place the info for Player1 in a first div and the things for Player2 in a second. Give the second div a `width` and a `float:right`